# Finding Solution For $yzz_x+xzz_y=2xy$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> $$yzz_x+xzz_y=2xy$$
>
> 1. Find a general solution
> 2. Find a particular solution given $x^2+y^2=16, z=3$

1. I solve using Lagrange

$$\frac{dx}{yz}=\frac{dy}{xz}=\frac{dz}{2xy}$$

Got $c_1=x^2-y^2$
and $c_2 =2y^2-z^2$

So a general solution is $$F(x^2-y^2)=2y^2-z^2$$

Or
$$z^2=2y^2-F(x^2-y^2)$$

2. Using the conditions we get:

$$9=2y^2-F(16-2y^2)$$

$$F(16-2y^2)=2y^2-9$$

$$F(t)=-t+7$$

So

$$z^2=x^2+y^2-7?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask if your result $\quad z^2=x^2+y^2-7\quad$ is correct.

Can't you check it by yourself ?

1. Find $zz_x$ and $zz_y$. Put them into the PDE and see if it's OK.
2. Put $x^2+y^2=16$ and $z=3$ into $z^2=x^2+y^2-7$ and see if it's OK.

Comment: Sorry, I started with an incorrect answer and manage to solve it